# rename multiple res/drawable png files in eclipse

Tags: android, png, android-drawable

In my res/drawawble directory in eclipse I have named my png files py (1), py (2)... py (120)!  I am unable to run my application on my emulator because the r.java file has killed itself due to my improper naming of my png files.  Is there a way for me to rename all my files quickly as opposed to renaming them one at a time?

Comment: Spaces and braces **aren't allowed** characters. Only small case letters, numbers (not beginning), dot and underscore are allowed. Other than this, use a **file renamer**. The question is **off-topic**, though.

Comment: I don't think so, if you want to do it fast go to yout project/res/drawable/ and rename all of the files, it will refresh on your project.

Comment: I wrote a tool because this was the first place I came to see if such a thing existed ... and it didn't. You can find it [here](https://github.com/wyattearp/android_res_renamer) and if you're on windows, you should be able to tweak up `line:34` to be `move` instead. Assuming you have git in your path, it will use `git mv` to rename the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux and Win32/Cygwin there is Midnight Commander (`mc`) which allows you to rename files like that (you will have to specify the "source mask"). Probably you also could do that using Far Manager (on Win), not sure. You definitely could do that using a bash script. Probably you also can write up a .bat file for batch renaming -- it *should* be possible, but I'm not sure about Windows stuff.

With `mc`,

[image]

gave me

[image]

`mc` keys: Ins to select/unselect 1 file, Gray + to select files by mask (Gray -/Gray * to unselect/invert), F6 to rename/move.

After renaming, you will have to refresh the workspace.